# Netlify CLI deploy command always asks for path

Tags: deployment, path, netlify

I used to have a file named .netlify which didn't work after their cli update.

Now it created this folder and file. The problem is that when I do `netlify deploy` it always asks for the deploy path even though I have it in the configuration...

any ideas?

.netlify/state.json:

```
{   
    "path": "dist",
    "siteId": "..."
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Nelify CLI looks for settings **locally** from two spots as [stated in the docs](https://www.netlify.com/docs/cli/#manual-deploys)

#### Flags

`netlify deploy --dir dist`

#### `netlify.toml` File (in project root)

```
[build]
  publish = "dist"
```

***NOTE:*** They will search in that order, so the command line flags will override what is in the `netlify.toml` file. Make sure you are using the latest version of the CLI.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that later!

I got confused because it put a path property in the state.json

Comment: I would not change the values in the `.netlify` folder unless the docs specifically tell you to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Use netlify deploy --dir dist for direct path input.
netlify.toml: In [build], set publish = "dist" for auto path.
Keep things smooth. Optimize your CLI deployment hassle!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).